Do they have quorum in the legislature in Sakartvelo? If so, how did they reach this?
I heard in a Youtube interview of an opposition leader who said that the ruling party would be unable to run the parliament without luring any of opposition members to participate. But I cannot find it now. Here is another source by the IA REGNUM: "Yes, it was formally formed not entirely legally: to open parliament, a quorum of 90 deputies out of 150 was needed, and the Dream had 84 mandates - the rest belonged to the opposition, which boycotted the sessions."*
Thus, the number of representatives of the ruling party would not be enough for a legal quorum, and since all the other four parties refused to participate, the legislature would be non-functional.
As such, my question is, how does the legislature apparently work despite this? Did they win some traitors from opposition parties who agreed to participate or was my initial information about the quorum wrong?

* "Да, формально сформированного не совсем законно: для открытия парламента нужен был кворум в 90 депутатов из 150, а у «Мечты» было 84 мандата — остальные у оппозиции, которая бойкотирует заседания." Source. traslation by Google

It is not clear to me that what you heard could be true. A quick search shows Georgia Dream with 89 members, but the quorum is 76.

@JamesK I heard it in a Youtube interview of an opposition leader who said that the ruling party would be unable to run the parliament without luring any of opposition members to participate. But I cannot find it now. Here is another source by the IA REGNUM: "Да, формально сформированного не совсем законно: для открытия парламента нужен был кворум в 90 депутатов из 150, а у «Мечты» было 84 мандата — остальные у оппозиции, которая бойкотирует заседания." https://regnum.ru/article/3932455

@RickSmith this source says the quorum is 90 while the ruling party has only 84: "Да, формально сформированного не совсем законно: для открытия парламента нужен был кворум в 90 депутатов из 150, а у «Мечты» было 84 мандата — остальные у оппозиции, которая бойкотирует заседания." https://regnum.ru/article/3932455

Only 52 MPs registered, whereas at least 76 MPs are needed for a quorum. Perhaps this article was mistaken. The "89 members" is in 2024 Georgian parliamentary election as "Seats won".
